# Can I host a VPN service on a shared Windows Host I already have?

Tags: vpn, web-hosting, shared-hosting, pptp, l2tp

I have a windows hosting plan with Plesk control panel, FTP, email and other popular options already found in common windows hosting plans. I want to know whether I can convert my hosting plan to a L2TP/IPSec or PPTP VPN service or not. Your answers are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what popular options are.

If you have Windows and you have full admin access to it, then can almost certainly run a VPN off it.  You will need a publicly routable IP.  Most VPN technologies do not work well through a NAT.  If you don't have a real IP from your provider, then you are probably out of luck.

Here is the Microsoft's page for [Routing and Remote Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545655).

If you do not have full access to the box, then you are probably out of luck.

Also, Microsoft has built-in [connection limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee344833%28WS.10%29.aspx) that are different depending on the edition of Windows you are running.  I believe the web edition does not even support RAS.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you actually have RDP access to the server, no.  Also, this is almost certainly a violation of your host's TOS.